# TextMate & Groovy

Tags: groovy, textmate, textmatebundles

I need help with TextMate. I installed it and want to compile Groovy within it (it seems convenient especially for trying things). I installed Groovy bundle but it doesn't work. It complains about:

```
Couldn't find /Applications/groovy-1.8.4/bin

If you have installed groovy, then you need to either update your PATH or set the 
TM_GROOVY shell variable (e.g. in Preferences / Advanced)

Locations searched:

/Users/meir/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Pristine Copy/Bundles/Groovy.tmbundle/Suppor
/bin
/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/bin/CocoaDialog.app/Contents/MacOS
/Users/meir/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Pristine Copy/Bundles/Groovy.tmbundle/Support
/bin
/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/bin/CocoaDialog.app/Contents/MacOS
/usr/bin 
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Applications/groovy-1.8.4/bin
/Applications/grails-1.3.7/bin
/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/bin
/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/bin
```

I tried to do everything. I added path (/Applications/groovy-1.8.4/bin) to TM_GROOVY in settings, add to PATH variable in the same settings and I even added it to the system path but no help at all.

Please help.

Comment: You could be more lucky posting this question to http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Does /Applications/groovy-1.8.4/bin exist on your Computer?

Comment: I put groovy into /Applications/groovy-1.8.4/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be clear you should click on TextMate > Preferences > Advanced > Shell Variables

Then add a Variable named 'TM_GROOVY' with the value being '/Applications/groovy-1.8.4/bin/groovy'

Not sure why but for my instance I actually have '.../groovy' specified explicitly.